How to match strings having optional group and not containing specific group?
How to match the following cases with regex:
XYZABC
ABC

but not these:
XYZ*ABC
*ABC

in order to capture the ABC part, which can be anything, including a (second) *?
I've tried the following, but it does not work.
(?:XYZ)?(?!\*)(.+)


This captures the XYZ too.

For me there is not enough  data. Depending on interpretation regex may change drastically. For example this looks fine and is simple: (?:XYZ)?(\w+) then fetching group(1) gives searched answer. Please specify exact constraints for ABC!

What if ABC would be AB*C?

@mike this is my question. Clearly specify you requirements. Your question do not explain what you are expecting in this case match or not?

https://godbolt.org/z/jTnGPExhn

I have specified now all the rules.

My approach should rather treat the exceptions, like ^(?!\*|XYZ\*)(.*) than having a more general expression. Or is there one?

@MarekR, the idea is to avoid any * or XYZ* prefix, but after that, any character is allowed, including any combination of * and/or XYZ.

@MarekR, I mean, AB*C should be accepted and matched, as it does not start with * or XYZ*.

@mike: That is what my regex is doing in the answer below. It capture AB*C when input is XYZAB*C or did I misunderstand your ask?

@anubhava, you are right, I have tried them as ECMA and that thrown an error.

Since you tagged it as boost/c++ I changed my regex to use possessive quantifier

You may use this regex with a possessive quantifier which is supported in boost c++ regex engine:
^(?:XYZ)?+(?!\*)(.*)

RegEx Demo
PS: Used \n inside negated character class for demo purpose only.
RegEx Details:

^: Start
(?:XYZ)?*: Match xyz optionally. Note that ?* is possessive quantifier to disallow backtracking
(?!\*): Make sure there is no * at the immediate next position
(.*): Match 0 or more of any characters and capture the value in group #1

